# How to get user profile info in Authorization code flow Azure AD B2C?

Tags: node.js, azure, react-native, azure-ad-b2c

In Auth Code flow, azure tenant provides a auth code upon successful authentication(`username/pwd`), then this code can be traded for `access_token`(useful to protect our resource APIs). When I use this `access_token` to get profile details using `graph /me` endpoint I'm getting invalid token exception. So, how can I get user profile details in this flow ?

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: Please let us know which process documents your following and error message

Comment: @Sruthi J- MSFT Identity  I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect to generate access_token and id_token. Im struck at getting user profile or updating profile using graph APIs. Can you help me get logged in user profile info after getting access_token? I am integrating a react native expo mobile app with azure AD B2C.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An access token can be used only for one resource.

The access token which is for your resource API cannot be used to call Microsoft Graph.

You should set `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access` during getting code and access token.

But currently it's **not supported** to get access token for Microsoft Graph via [Request an access token in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens). It's only for protecting your APIs.

You need to follow [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) to get the access token with Auth Code flow.

Comment: The on behalf flow is not supported by B2C... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

Comment: @AlexAIT "Get access on behalf of a user" is the name of the article. It doesn't mean on behalf of flow. It's auth code flow in fact.

Answer (score 0):

[Implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa) is the only flow supported for SPA. Authorization code flow is intended for webapps, mobile and desktop apps but not for SPA.Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows)

Comment: Yes, I am using Auth code flow only in my mobile App

Comment: Please refer to this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples#mobile-and-desktop-apps) that may help you